# How to install libreadline.so.7 on Ubuntu 22

Tags: psql, postgres-11

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 machine where I need to install PostgreSQL 11.9 and its client (psql). Psql requires libreadline.so.7 and it is not available in the Ubuntu repositories. Only libreadline.so.8 is present in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu folder.

Now I am not able to find a way to install this library via apt-get, so I would like to know if it is safe to create a symbolic link like this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7
```

psql seems to work fine but since this is code that must go in production I want to know if it is safe. I would like to avoid build from source.